# Display video modally on part of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

I'm trying to display a video when my game ends (after a few minutes).

Here are the requirements :

- The video is presented modally. Once it ends, it stays still on the last picture and the game can only be restarted by relaunching the app (this behavior is wanted)
- The video does not have any control (no pause, no "Done" button etc.)
- **Most importantly** : It does not occupy the whole screen. I want for example to display it in the middle of the screen, approximatively at 50% of the main screen size. (I need to see the VC underneath with a gray/transparent effect)

I achieved this using MPMoviePlayerController, but I did not notice that it was deprecated. So I'm now using AVPlayerViewController (added directly on storyboard)

This way I can :

- Present it modally (using segue)
- Set a grey/transparent background so that I can see the VC underneath
- Disable the controls

But I **CAN'T** prevent it from resizing my video (I bet because videoGravity resizes it)

Here is my code :

```
    // Game over
    case GameSegue.GameEndSegue.rawValue:

        // Get photo VC
        let videoVC = segue.destinationViewController as! AVPlayerViewController
        videoVC.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve

        // Remove controls on the video
        videoVC.showsPlaybackControls = false

        // Get video URL and provide it to the player
        let videoURL  = helperClass.urlForFile(videoName)
        videoVC.player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)

        videoVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.6)

        // This doesn't change anything (hard coded for example)
        videoVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)

        // Play video
        videoVC.player?.play()
```

Can someone please help on this ?